# Increase performance: avoid looking for the right element in a collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this situation.

activity.rb

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :cause
belongs_to :sub_cause
belongs_to :client

def amount
  duration / 60.0 * user.hourly_cost_by_year(date.year).amount rescue 0
end
```

user.rb

```
has_many :hourly_costs # one hourly_cost for year
has_many :activities

def hourly_cost_by_year(year = Date.today.year)
  hourly_costs.find { |hc| hc.year == year }
end
```

hourly_cost.rb

```
belongs_to :user
```

I have a big report where I achieved good performance (the number of SQL queries is fixed) but I think I could do better. The query I use is

```
activities = Activity.includes(:client, :cause, :sub_cause, user: :hourly_costs)
```

And this is ok, it's fast, but I think is improvable because `hourly_cost_by_year` method. I mean, activity has a date and I can use that date to know which of those hourly costs I should use. Something like this in `activity`

```
def self.user_with_single_hourly_cost
  joins('LEFT JOIN users u ON u.id = activities.user_id').
  joins('LEFT JOIN hourly_costs hc ON hc.user_id = u.id AND hc.year = EXTRACT(year from activities.date)')
end
```

But I don't how integrate this in my query. Whatever I tried did not work. I could use raw SQL but I'm trying to use ActiveRecord. I even thought to use redis to cache every hourly cost by user and year, could work, but I think this query, with the extract part, should do the best job because I'd have a flat table.

Update: I try to clarify. Whatever query I use in my action at some point I have to do

```
activities.sum(&:amount)
```

and that method, you know, is

```
def amount
  duration / 60.0 * user.hourly_cost_by_year(date.year).amount rescue 0
end
```

And I don't know how to pick directly the hourly_cost I want without search between hourly_costs. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may consider using [`Arel`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/rails/arel) for this. `Arel` is the underlying query assembler for rails/activerecord (so no new dependencies) and can be very useful when building complex queries because it offers far more depth than the high level `ActiveRecord::QueryMethods`.

Obviously with a broader API comes more verbosity (which actually adds quite a bit to the readability) and less syntactical sugar which takes some getting used to but has proven indispensable for me on multiple occasions.

While I did not take the time to recreate your data structure something like this may work for you

```
activities = Activity.arel_table
users = User.arel_table
hourly_costs = HourlyCost.arel_table

activity_users_hourly_cost = activities
  .join(users,Arel::Nodes::OuterJoin)
    .on(activities[:user_id].eq(users[:id]))
  .join(hourly_costs,Arel::Nodes::OuterJoin)
    .on(hourly_costs[:user_id].eq(users[:id])
      .and(hourly_costs[:year].eq(Arel::Nodes::Extract.new(activities[:date],'year'))
    )
  )
Activity.includes(:client, :cause, :sub_cause).joins(activity_users_hourly_cost.join_sources)
```

This will add the requested join e.g.

```
activity_users_hourly_cost.to_sql 
#=> SELECT 
    FROM [activities] 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [users] ON [activities].[user_id] = [users].[id] 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [hourly_costs] ON [hourly_costs].[user_id] = [users].[id] 
        AND [hourly_costs].[year] = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM [activities].[date])
```

**Update**

If you just want to add the "hourly_cost" this should work for you

```
  Activity.includes(:client, :cause, :sub_cause)
    .joins(activity_users_hourly_cost.join_sources)
    .select("activities.*, activities.duration / 60.0 * ISNULL([hourly_costs].[amount],0) as hourly_cost_by_year")
```

Please note that this will only return `Activity` objects but they will now have a method called `hourly_cost_by_year` which will return the result of that calculation. Full SQL will look like

```
   SELECT 
     [activities].*,
     activities.duration / 60.0 * ISNULL([hourly_costs].[amount],0) as hourly_cost_by_year
    FROM [activities]
    -- Dependant upon WHERE Clause 
     LEFT OUTER JOIN causes ON [activities].[cause_id] = [causes].[id]
     LEFT OUTER JOIN sub_causes ON [activities].[subcause_id] = [subcauses].[id]
     LEFT OUTER JOIN clients [activities].[client_id] = [clients].[id]
    --
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [users] ON [activities].[user_id] = [users].[id] 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [hourly_costs] ON [hourly_costs].[user_id] = [users].[id] 
        AND [hourly_costs].[year] = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM [activities].[date])
```

You could build the select portion in `Arel` too if you like but seems overkill for such a simple statement.

Comment: Man, query works but it worked mine too. Problem is the call to `hourly_cost_by_year` in this line `duration / 60.0 * user.hourly_cost_by_year(date.year).amount rescue 0`

Comment: I mean, I don't know how to point to the right hourly_cost without use find on hourly_costs

Comment: @Ursus in the simplest terms please explain what you would like as the result and I will be glad to help you build a query to get it. Is user the top level table you want to target? You can post the desired Sql if you want. If it is valid Arel can build it

Comment: @Ursus is the only result you care about the "amount" or do you need additional information in the query itself. e.g. the activity, the user, the client etc.?

Comment: The amount is the only data I need while I'm building the report. Then, I have to return user, client etc as well, but they don't need elaboration

Comment: @Ursus So you want to select all the above with an additional column for "amount" is that correct or is a secondary query a sufficient solution

Comment: I want to select all the activities flat with its amount in hourly_cost even if one user has many hourly costs

Comment: @Ursus given the fact that you want to eager load alot of information and want to preform an aggregation,  these should probably be separate concerns. The SQL that would have to be generated for this would be extremely convoluted and would actually impede performance because you are aggregating a single column but will have to group by every single other column. I could write this for you in Arel outside of ActiveRecord but i do not believe that is what you would want. My suggestion is keep what you have and don't worry about the performance if it isn't actually an issue.

Comment: @Ursus after reviewing your intentions i have updated my post and maybe that will help ?

Comment: Here we go, super fast :) I was thinking about define the virtual field in the select as well. it was so easy in the end

Comment: @Ursus glad it worked out for you. As a note that `Arel` can be placed into a scope for easy reference if you needed it. Good luck

Comment: Thank you @engineersmnky, very kind