# Left Outer Joins Rails, with condition on left table doesn't include all right table records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, join, activerecord

I am using Rails 5 and Postgresql. My Models as follow:
Variant has_many line_items
LineItem belongs_to Order
Order has_many LineItems

What I need to do is Left outer join the variants table with the line_items and orders in order to calculate sum of orders and total amount grouped by variant. I need to left join Variant with orders completed on specific date range, however adding this condition on orders table (right side of join ) results in excluding many records from Left Side the variant. Below is my original query

```
Spree::Variant.left_outer_joins(line_items: :order)
                  .where(spree_orders: { completed_at: params[:start_date]..params[:end_date] })
                  .select('spree_variants.*, SUM(spree_line_items.quantity) as sales_count, SUM(spree_line_items.quantity * spree_line_items.price) as sales_amount')
                  .group('spree_variants.root_variant_id, spree_variants.id')
```

What I am trying to do now is to include the condition of date between in the join but always getting an error, here is what I am trying to do and cant find the error.

```
Spree::Variant.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN spree_line_items ON spree_line_items.variant_id = spree_variants.id LEFT OUTER JOIN spree_orders ON spree_orders.id = spree_line_items.order_id AND spree_orders.completed_at BETWEEN #{params[:start_date]} AND #{params[:end_date]}")
                  .select('spree_variants.*, SUM(spree_line_items.quantity) as sales_count, SUM(spree_line_items.quantity * spree_line_items.price) as sales_amount')
                  .group('spree_variants.root_variant_id, spree_variants.id')
```

The params of start_date and end_date are as follow:

```
params[:end_date] = Time.current.end_of_day
params[:start_date] = (Time.current - 200.days).beginning_of_day
```

i.e params[:end_date]

> Mon, 04 Feb 2019 23:59:59 EET +02:00

The SQL produced by my second query is duplicated, it produce 2 exact sql queries 
Anyone has a better solution or an idea how to fix this?

Comment: A left join with a condition on the right side is an inner join. Not much you can do about that since it is the only logical solution. What you would need is a sub query with a left join against it to get what you are looking for or 2 queries 1 for all the left side and one for the filtered right side. My answer in [This Post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44575401/1978251) may be of assistance